# Alternativas a GitHub para alojar un repositorio local

Tags: git, github, google-drive, almacenamiento

Hoy me he encontrado con un problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo visto mis archivos ocupan demasiada memoria para el plan que tengo contratado.
Para tener un repositorio privado en GitHub tengo que pagar unos 6 euros al mes, que no me permite alojar más de 100 MB según se ve en la imagen.
He visto que google drive te da 100 gigas por 2 euros al mes.
Me pregunto si podría alojar en google drive un repositorio privado y usar los comandos git push y git pull con el desde mi consola de comandos en mi portátil, es decir usarlo como uso GitHub.

Comment: node_modules no deberia estar subido a tu repo git... porque lo subis?

Comment: @gbianchi: cosas de principiante...no he caído. Si, si...si estoy mirando como hacer para no tenerlo que subir.

Comment: debe estar en tu git ignore.. solo debes subir los fuentes del codigo...

Comment: Por si acaso, bitbucket puede ofrecer más.

Comment: @Alfabravo igual al solucion es agregarlo al `.gitignore` y luego un buen manual de instalacion

Comment: Una alternativa a gitHub es [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in) se pueden tener proyectos privados de forma gratuita (con limitaciones en el numero de colaboradores en el proyecto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los archivos compilado o producidos  por tu aplicacion no deben subirse a github ya que por lo general son archivos grandes y que se pueden generar a partir de tu codigo, para evitar subirlo lo debes agregar a tu archivo `gitignore`, editas el archivo y agregas la linea:

```
node_modules/
```

Eso hara que no se suba nada de esa carpeta pero seguirá estando en tu proyecto local.
Si aun asi quieres usar Google drive para versionar tu codigo te dejo [esta](https://medium.com/@techstreams/git-google-drive-simple-git-host-3a84db4fc1fd) referencia

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Voy a cambiar mi forma de proceder con git desde ahora usaré el archivo git ignore. Pero mi pregunta sigue vigente ¿Puedo interactuar con Google Drive a través de git?